# WKB form manipulation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

If I have the equation $$y'' +\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)y = 0$$ and I approximate $\sin(\frac1x)$ as $\frac1x$, how would I get epsilon squared in front of the first term (which is required for WKB form)?

I have tried defining $\delta X=\frac1x$, but that doesn't help at all. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That's not suitable to use WKB on, except perhaps if you are restricting attention to large $x$ (which would make sense for your proposed approximation of $\sin(1/x)$). In that vein, if you assume that the domain is say $[M,\infty)$ then you can look at $x=Mz$ where $z \in [1,\infty)$ and then $\frac{d^2}{dz^2}=M^{-2} \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$ which creates your small parameter $M^{-1}$. So you get $\varepsilon^2 y'' + \sin(\varepsilon z^{-1}) y = 0$ and you can now at least in principle apply the WKB method.

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti That would make the substitution into WKB form really messy. I end up with the integral of  with respect to /\epsilon^2 as the exponent?

Comment: I don't understand the difficulty. You should completely change variables to $z=M^{-1} x$ and identify $\varepsilon=M^{-1}$. Now the equation you're studying is $\varepsilon^2 \frac{d^2 y}{dz^2} + \sin(\varepsilon z^{-1}) y = 0$. You can now apply WKB to that equation if you want, or you could try some other perturbative technique based on writing $\sin(\varepsilon z^{-1})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \varepsilon^{2n+1} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} z^{-2n-1}$. Either way it would probably be wise to divide through by $\varepsilon$ so that the coefficient of $y$ is $\Theta(1)$.